# Using pip install when using automatic configuration script for proxy settings

Tags: python-3.x, pip, environment-variables

While I try to do:

```
Pip install robotframework
```

I get a connection timedout error message.

I am using configuration script for my proxy

Could someone tell how to add this detail to environment variable or any other method to over come this ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into your configuration script.
After that you can specify the required parameters in the following command:

```
pip install --proxy http://user:password@proxyserver:port robotframework
```